# Angular application 404 on refresh with NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I have a angular application which serve using Nginx. But when I refresh it after go to a page it gives 404 error (For example in www.test.uk/angular/user).

Following is my config file. I used three location blocks for different parts of the web site. Among this second location block is for angular. (First part is for api and last part is for php based web site.)

Tried many solutions but none of them works. Please help me to resolve this.

```
server {
    server_name  test.uk www.test.uk;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

     root /var/www;
     location /angular/ {
         try_files $uri $uri/ angular/index.html;
     }


     location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm experiencing the same thing.